# Validate form, then show animation, then submit the form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-submit

I try to execute a function after hitting a button if the form is valid:

```
  const elForm = document.getElementById("addressForm");

  elForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    
    var isValid = elForm.checkValidity();
    if (isValid) {
      // If there is no validation error
      // Stop the submit button
      event.preventDefault(); 
      // execute the loading animation
      loadingAnimation();
      // now submit the form and redirect to the success page
      elForm.submit();
    }

  });
```

This does not work.

What I'm trying to achieve here:

1. Upon hitting the submit button, check if there are validation errors
2. If not then prevent the form from submitting
3. Execute a loading animation function (this simply adds a loading spinner via css)
4. After completing the loading animation submit the form and redirect accordingly

I don't understand why this is not working. Isn't the JavaScript parser just executing one instruction after the other?

How would I have to write this?

Comment: You should add the ```submit()``` as a callback function for your ```loadingAnimation()```.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `submit()` function as a callback function to your `loadingAnimation()`.

When you call your `loadingAnimation(submit);` like this.

Now, inside your `loadingAnimation()` you can call the `submit()` after the animation is completed.

Pseudocode:

```
loadingAnimation(submit);

function loadingAnimation(callback){
 //Code for your animation
 callback(); //Your submit function will be called.
}
```

Below is the demo code:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () =>{

  let fullName = document.querySelector("#full-name");
  let error = document.querySelector(".error");
  
  const isValid = validateForm(fullName.value);

  if(isValid){
    loadindAnimation(submitForm);
  }
  else{
    fullName.style.border = "2px solid red";
    error.innerText = "Full name must be more then 5 characters long."
  }
  
});


function validateForm(userInput){
  if(userInput.length < 5)
    return false;
  
  return true;
}


function loadindAnimation(callback){
  var animationInterval = setInterval(animationTimer, 1000);
  
  function animationTimer() {
    console.log("Loading Animation for 3 seconds.....");
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
     clearInterval(animationInterval);
     callback()
  }, 3000);
}



function submitForm(){
 console.log("Submitting the Form")
}
```

```css
.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="full-name" />
<br>
<span class="error"></span>
<br><br>
<button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
```